# Best option with 3ware 3DM2 when drive has bad sectors?

Tags: raid, failover, 3ware

I have a FreeBSD server running a RAID 5 array using the 3ware hardware controller 3DM2 ([user guide PDF](http://www.aberdeeninc.com/abcatg/manual/Aberdeen/3DM-2.pdf)).

It uses 3 hot-swap drives + 1 spare.

The last couple of months one of the drives have experienced bad sectors, so I get a lot of alert e-mails like this:

```
20101105201229 - Controller 0
WARNING - Sector repair completed: port=2, LBA=0xBAB4594
```

Yesterday I then started also getting these:

```
20101107192948 - Controller 0
ERROR - Drive timeout detected: port=2
```

And:

```
20101108000011 - Controller 0
WARNING - SMART threshold exceeded: port=2
```

I can of cause wait for the drive on port 2 to fail completely - or I could just manually take it offline and let the spare kick in.

**Which is the best/safest option?**

Thanks :)

/thomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take it out now, and put a new spare in as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes. Sounds classically like a disc starting to fail. Expecially the SMART warning is pertty clear. Take it out. Put in a spare.

Comment: Thanks... The spare drive have now take over and rebuild is complete. Now I'll just have to get a new spare and get to the data-center to put it in :)

Answer (score 1):

First check for vibration. If the PC house is vibrating change your ventillators. Had lot of trouble until (finally) found out this simple solution.

No sector repairs (and other fancy things since).

Zsolt